# EditText XML reference issue

Tags: java, android, xml

Hoping this is a simple one.

I have a very simple issue here that I cant seem to solve. I'm simply trying to reference an EditText in my XML layout to the code through the use of findViewById etc. For some reason, and I have tried cleaning the project and regenerating my R resource file, along with ctrl+o to check the imports I cant get Eclipse to 'see' the link to the EditText in the XML layout.

Hopefully someone can help me with this frustrating and simple error.

Currently the error is:

```
totalListPrice cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

This is the simple code used to reference 'totalListPrice; in my XML to the EditText in my code:

```
totalPrice = (EditText)findViewById(android.R.id.totalListPrice);
```

And this is my XML layout (the problematic EditText has been marked):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLink"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/viewcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Shopping List"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemDes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Search From An Item In The List:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAppointName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter An Item Name" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"/>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56px"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total Price:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     *************ERROR*************
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/totalListPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"></EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
R.id.totalListPrice
```

not

```
android.R.id.totalListPrice
```

Import local `R` class in your java file instead the `R` class of android framework

```
import <your package name>.R;
```

Comment: Many thanks....this was due to me looking at my listview whicb requires android. many thanks

Comment: Next time be careful when including `R` class

Comment: If this was the solution to your problem, think about accepting it as an answer for future users!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "android" in front of the R. Instead, import the generated R file from your own package (you should be able to delete the `import android.R` line and replace it with your R import easily).

It should just be `R.id.totalListPrice`.